# Skip stdin and stderr of child with pexpect

Tags: python, ipc, pexpect, pty

I'm controlling a child process using [`pexpect`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pexpect) (because `subprocess` [doesn't support pty's](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0324/) and I run into a deadlock with two pipes). The process creates a lot of output on `stderr`, in which I'm not interested, and apparantly `pexpect` also echoes back anything I write to its `stdin`:

```
>>> import pexpect
>>> p = pexpect.spawn('rev')
>>> p.sendline('Hello!')
7
>>> p.readline()
'Hello!\r\n'
>>> p.readline()
'!olleH\r\n'
```

How can I turn this off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using pty's is not quite the same as a pipe. If you don't put in in raw mode the tty driver will echo back the characters and perform other line editing. So to get a clean data path you need to also put the pty/tty in raw mode.

Since you are now dealing with a pseudo device you have only a single I/O stream. There is no distinction there between stdout and stderr (that is a userspace convention). So you will always see stdout and stderr mixed when using a pty/tty.